# ADO Connection fails to open to UPDATE an SQL database

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have an SQL database and I want to update a specific table and specific fields.

I insert records from an Excel spreadsheet into another database I created that uses the dbo schema.

I wrote a stored procedure with an UPDATE in my play database that updates a table in the erp schema. If I execute the sp in SSMS it works. If I execute the sp from Excel it fails.

I update the Play database table is by executing a SELECT sp, returning the recordset to a spreadsheet and then creating and executing an UPDATE for each row. Of course, this take longer to accomplish.

Here is the code for the UPDATE stored procedure.  For testing purposes, my procedure now returns the following line from SQL

`SELECT @Rows AS i_Rows, DATEDIFF(MS,@Start, @End) / 1000 AS i_Seconds, (DATEDIFF(MS,@Start, @End) - (DATEDIFF(MS,@Start, @End)/1000)) AS i_Miliseconds`

```vb
Sub ExecuteProc()
    Dim o_Connection As ADODB.Connection, o_Recordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim o_Command As ADODB.Command
    Dim s_ConnString As String, s_StoredProcName As String, s_ProjectID, s_Name, s_SQL1 As String
    Dim b_ProjHours, b_JobHours, b_Dates As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim l_row, l_count  As Long
    Dim t_Start, t_End As Date
    Dim i_Seconds As Integer

    ' Determine the values of certain variables
    With ActiveSheet
        s_Name = .Name
        b_JobHours = .chkHours.Value
        b_Dates = .chkDates.Value
        s_ProjectID = .Cells(15, "B").Value
    End With

    DataWS

    ' Make UpdateJobOper the selected sheet
    With Worksheets("DATA")
        .Select
        .Cells.ClearContents
    End With

    ' Create new Connection, Recordset, Command, and Connection String
    Set o_Connection = New ADODB.Connection
    Set o_Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set o_Command = New ADODB.Command
    s_ConnString = "Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=SQLSERVER;DATABASE=Play;UID=BIExcel;PWD=BIExcel;WSID=;"

    On Error GoTo CloseConnection

    ' Open the Connection using the connection string
    o_Connection.Open s_ConnString

    ' Stored Procedure Name and Project ID parameter
    s_StoredProcName = "Play.dbo.BIspUpateJobOper"

    ' Define the command used to open the stored procedure
    With o_Command
        .ActiveConnection = o_Connection
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = s_StoredProcName
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ProjectID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, s_ProjectID)
    End With
    ' Return the recordset using the command and paste it into the DATA worksheet starting at cell A2
    Set o_Recordset = o_Command.Execute
    Sheets("DATA").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset o_Recordset

    ' Close the recordset and connection to the SQL Server
    o_Recordset.Close
    o_Connection.Close
    On Error GoTo 0
    On Error GoTo 0
    DeleteDataWS
    Exit Sub

CloseConnection:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    DeleteDataWS
    MsgBox "Failed to open SQL Connection", vbCritical, "SQL Error"
    o_Connection.Close
End Sub

Public Function last_row_with_data(ByVal lng_column_number As Long, shCurrent As Variant) As Long
    last_row_with_data = shCurrent.Cells(Rows.Count, lng_column_number).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Sub DataWS()
    ' Add a new worksheet called DATA
    ' If the worksheet already exists, clear it
    On Error GoTo AddSheet
    With Sheets("DATA")
        .Select
        .Cells.ClearContents
    End With
    Exit Sub
    ' If it does not exist add it
AddSheet:
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "DATA"
End Sub

Sub DeleteDataWS()
    On Error GoTo GetOutOfHere
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("DATA").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
GetOutOfHere:
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you post the complete UPDATE stored proc code rather than the irrelevant `SELECT` query. Just a guess since you did not provide details of what "fails" means but make sure the stored procedure includes `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Comment: What happens if you skip a stored procedure and just execute the update directly? ie o_connection.execute "update fred set fild1 = 2 where fild2='Harry'"